# android button click event is not working for me

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

I have an android application with relative layout where i have placed a button control like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalc"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="708dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="@string/btncalc" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And For testing the event i have placed toast on click event of this button like this

```
btncalcu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //calc();
            }

        });
```

Problem is that when i run the application there is not error or any exception but also nothing displayed there of `Toast`.Any Can Guess what may b the issue .Plz Help !

Comment: can you add the full activity class code here?

Comment: use only this instead of getBaseContext()

Comment: Did you declare the activity in the Android Manifest File? sometimes, we forget to declare the activity, and button click don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply try this way instead and see if it works,

```
    btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

And make sure you have imported the following,

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: did u try changing the baseContext to v.getContext()?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
btncalcu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Calculation Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

And import this line

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just 1 tip

Check if button is enabled or not

in xml

> android:enabled="false"

to

> android:enabled="true"

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj Anytime Bro!

Answer (score 1):

Just try out this way:

> ```
> btncalcu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
>     btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ <---Change `View.Onclick` instead of `Button`
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v)
>         {
>             Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>             //calc();
>         }
>     });
> ```

And make sure you have imported the following,

`import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `YourActivity.this` as the context, do not use `getBaseContext()`.

```
btncalcu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //calc();
            }

        });
```

The context is used to tell the application where to show the Toast, so using the current activity is advised.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getBaseContext()`, use the context that you have `v.getContext()`.

Resolution:

```
Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btncalcu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(yourActivityclassname.this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //calc();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

to ways to solve this:

1.

```
btncalcu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(YourActivityname.this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //calc();
            }

        });
```

2.

```
  btncalcu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
            btncalcu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //calc();
                }

            });
```

and must check that have you imported this import:

```
android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `View.OnClickListener()` instead of `Button.OnClickListener()`. It will solve your problem

Also `getBaseContext()` will no doubt work for you, but it is preferred to use `ActivityName.this` for `Toasts`, to prevent any memory leakages.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a listView check if have applied any elevation to it. I did the same and had floating button on top of the listView and hence the button never got clicked. You can't make it out unless you check the xml file. The code that I had written just for your reference.

Remove the elevation and do the onClick. Quite logical, works after you do so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/fullListViewToDo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#F3F3F3"
        android:dividerHeight="8.0sp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:elevation="8dp">

    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/todo_fragmentContainer">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was for an Android TV device.

Issue resolved by adding below code for the view where click is required with the parent view and attached the id with the click listener.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

Use like this:

```
btncalcu..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // or

             Toast.makeText(YourActivityname.this, "Clicked Button",, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Works for me.